# Deleting columns from text files with sed

Tags: sed

I would like to delete columns 1,2,4,5,6,10,11,12 from space delimited text files.I want to delete these columns from the existing files instead of printing output. How can I do this with sed?

```
MMMM   1522  KL1 PPP A 201      -7.299   41.933  48.192  1.00 31.52           G
MMMM     22  G   SSS A   3       39.541  25.078  -2.722  1.00 30.47           B
```

Desired output

```
KL1    -7.299   41.933  48.192
G       39.541  25.078  -2.722
```

Comment: Are there any columns beyond column 12?  If so, how many?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sed` wouldn't be ideal. Use `cut`:

```
cut -d ' ' --complement -f -2,4-6,10-12 file.txt
```

***EDIT:***

From additional information from the comments:

```
< file.txt awk '{ print $3, $7, $8, $9 }' | column -t
```

Results:

```
KL1  -7.299  41.933  48.192
G    39.541  25.078  -2.722
```

To overwrite your file, you'll need to use a temporary file:

```
< file.txt awk '{ print $3, $7, $8, $9 }' | column -t > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code doesn't work. I want to delete columns from the existing files.Please help me.

Comment: @lara: Could you be a little more specific? What is your error message? Is your delimiter a single space, any amount of whitespace or a tab? The code is working correctly. Perhaps you should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13717128/edit) your question to include some sample input.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to delete columns from the original files instead of printing the output?

Comment: @lara: Yes it is, I just re-read your question. Please see the edit above. You'll need to use a temp file because `awk` doesn't offer in-place editing like `sed` does.

Answer (score 2):

If is is a real task (not homework) it is better to do with `awk`:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if (i != 1 && i!=2 && i!=4 && i!=5 && i!=6 && i!=10 && i!=11 && i!=12) printf("%s ", $i);  printf("\n"); }' f.txt
```

Or if you need to print only columns number 3, 7, 8, 9 :

```
awk '{print $3" "$7" "$8" "$9}' f.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(\S+\s+){3}(\S+\s+){3}((\S+\s+){2}\S+).*/\1\3/' file
```

Or alternatively:

```
sed -r 's/^\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+\s+)\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+).*/\1\2/' file
```

or for most sed variations:

```
sed -e 's/^[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *\([^ ][^ ]*  *\)[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *\([^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*\).*/\1\2/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12"|perl -F -ane '$F[0]=$F[1]=$F[3]=$F[4]=$F[5]=$F[9]=$F[10]=$F[11]="";print "@F";'
  3    7 8 9
```

in awk:

```
echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12" | awk '{$1=$2=$4=$5=$6=$10=$11=$12="";print}'
3    7 8 9
```