# delete lines if $4 is one

Tags: sed, awk

I would like to delete the lines from text files if $4 is one

```
123  34  A   0
23   45  A   1  
36   5   A   36
176  3   A   1
```

desired output

```
123  34  A   0
36   5   A   36
```

I need in-place editing. How can I do this with awk or sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `GNU sed` with `-i` for in-place editing and `-r` for extended regular expressions:

```
sed -ri '/^\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+1( |$)/d' file
```

If you desperately need in-place editing, you may also like to try `perl` with it's auto-split functionality. The code is much more readable and portable too:

```
perl -i -ane 'print if $F[3] != 1' file
```

Results:

```
123  34  A   0
36   5   A   36
```

Comment: Are you sure about the `\S` and `\s` notations?  They're from PCRE, but the GNU `sed` manual pages on [Regular Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions) and [Extended Regular Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-regexps) don't mention those notations.  Could there be a doc bug?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes. I've always been under the impression that `\S` and `\s` are EREs (and PCREs). I also think that more documentation is a good thing.

Comment: I've just checked with GNU sed 4.2.2 from December 2012, and it does not support the `\s` or `\S` notations and the `sed` command you propose does not work, therefore.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Are you completely sure you're using the version of `sed` that you state? I believe you may have gotten your installations mixed up. I can confirm that the given command will work with `GNU sed version 4.2.1`, which pre-dates yours - and I highly doubt support for `\S` and `\s` would have been depreciated. That would be silly. The notation is in fact standard (as an ERE) and I've seen plenty of answers like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717128/deleting-columns-from-text-files-with-sed) before.

Comment: I've just retried it — it appears I made a mistake last night.  I'm not sure what I did wrong.  I've taken another look at the GNU documentation; the sequence backslash-s and backslash-S does not appear in it.  Nor is either of those documented in the POSIX RE (BRE and ERE) notations.

Answer (score 5):

In `awk`:

```
awk '$4 != 1'
```

It is doable in `sed`, but sufficiently much harder that I'd not bother:

```
sed '/^[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *1 *$/d'
```

Or, if you've got GNU `sed`:

```
sed -r '/^[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +1 *$/d'
```

Comment: +1 for the awk solution. Hard to believe people would prefer a complicated sed solution just to get in-place editing rather than a simple `awk file > tmp && mv tmp file` but thankfully an upcoming gawk release will support in-place editing so then we can stop the insanity....

Comment: @EdMorton: I'd hardly call it complicated, although I do personally prefer the Perl solution. Either way, in-place editing is much more convenient when run as root which may be why the OP requires it. Just a guess. Re the gawk news, I can't wait :-)

Comment: @steve - Well, you referred to the perl code as "much more readable" and Jonathan referred to the sed code as "sufficiently much harder that I'd not bother" which both sound to me like just another way of saying that the sed code is complicated but YMMV I suppose. What do you mean when you say "in-place editing is much more convenient when run as root"? sed just uses a tmp file behind the scenes so it's not like it's really editing the file in-place so I don't get why being logged in as root should matter wrt permissions or anything.

Comment: @EdMorton: I just meant `sudo sed -i '...'` looks a bit cleaner compared to `sudo sh -c "awk '...' a > b && mv b a"` although yes the effect is the ultimately the same. Handling any quoting inside of `awk` is what I start to find inconvenient, especially with lots of print and printf statements.

Comment: @steve: If you can write `sudo sed -i '...'`, why not write `sudo awk '...'` avoiding the `sh -c "..."` complexities?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I thought the `sh -c` was necessary to ensure that the redirection and replacement has the necessary permissions. Am I missing something here? I get `Permission denied` without it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be different...

```
$ ed << \eof
g- 1$-d
w
q
eof
```

Comment: That assumes there are exactly four fields and no trailing spaces; that's good for the existing sample data, but not necessarily for all other data.  Of course, it is hard to be perfectly general.

Answer (score 0):

with awk

`awk '{if($4 != 1 ) print $0}' temp.txt`

Comment: How is this different to Jonathan's answer 6 hours earlier?

Comment: @steve That was in short form. i always try write without shortcuts. Its easy for new user to see whats happenning. That previous solution looks small and good solution from awks view but me being a  new user , try me write in full way so that person new to awk can see that if is condition and like that. i also try to see the solution of less experienced user because that makes more sense to me as he usually writes in less compact form which is easy to understand. but fore more experienced user they write in few characetrs which are difficult to grasp

Comment: The last point you make is arguable. Regardless, if you wish to make your point, I would prefer to see your solution as a comment under Jonathan's answer, rather than as an answer itself. Remember SO is a Q&A site, not some sort of forum. And I'm certain the OP would ask the answerer if he/she didn't understand the code or wanted more explanation.

Comment: @steve , actually i didnt thought of adding that in comment, but i will take care next time. But i have seen 50% of time if solution works then OP just copy paste it without understanding. i have seen many solutions as accepted but with no comments by new users. and i had to do some research to understand those that whats the meaning of those.Even i had to ask the person to explain. and i think i have done that many times with your answer :)

Comment: If I was going to do it without the short form, I'd use: `awk '$4 != 1 { print $0 }'`, using the explicit pattern-action notation that `awk` supports.  You have all action; my answer has all pattern; the version here has both pattern and action.  The `$0` is optional of course; a plain `print` prints `$0` anyway.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that pattern action thing is really confusiong. i am using it for 1 months and still was confused that's why i was not able to figure out that why i can't use if outside the braces. i tried and it was ging the error. Now you have cleared that using if becomes the `action`. you see its gets time to learn the things. i tried reading notes but things get clearer slowly with experience